# Ruby not creating a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to get ruby on rails to start a test app for 3 days now. I am a total noob but I am just trying to get rails running. I am getting an error

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.10.9 (x64-mingw32)
Installing nokogiri 1.10.9 (x64-mingw32)
Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, <
2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.9' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 6.0.2.2, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 6.0.2.2, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 6.0.2.2, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 6.0.2.2, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'webpacker (~> 4.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile.
       rails  webpacker:install
Could not find gem 'webpacker (~> 4.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources li
sted in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I uninstalled and reinstalled like 4 times

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, I think: Nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.3 and < 2.7. You have 2.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows what you need to do:

```
Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, <
2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.
```

Install ruby < 2.7 and > 2.3, you have 2.7.1.83.